# What would be the correct asymptotic lower bound for $f(n) = 3n^2 + 2n$?

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

What is the correct asymptotic lower bound for $f(n) = 3n^2 + 2n$?

I was thinking that the lower bound would simply be $\omega(n) = cn^2 + n$, for the constant $c = 3$ and integer $n \ge 1$. Indeed, $3n^2 + 2n \ge 3n^2 + n$ is the tightest lower bound I can come up with.

However, would this be the correct answer instead?  $\omega(n) = cn^2$ for the constant $c = 3$ and integer $n \ge 1$? Are we allowed to drop variables of a lower order when producing an asymptotic lower bound?

Comment: Every function is its own asymptotic lower bound.

Comment: *Are we allowed... ?* You are allowed to do anything you want. The concept *asymptotic lower bound* has a particular mathematical definition. Any function which satisfies the definition is an asymptotic lower bound. No more, no less. This is how mathematical definitions work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $g(n)$ is an asymptotic lower bound for a function $f(n)$, in symbols $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$, if the following holds:

> There exist $N,c > 0$ such that for all $n \geq N$: $f(n) \geq cg(n)$.

In your case, $f(n) = 3n^2 + 2n$. You can check that $f(n) = \Omega(f(n))$, that is, the function is its own asymptotic lower bound. Similarly, you can check that $f(n) = \Omega(3n + 2)$, that is, $3n+2$ is an asymptotic lower bound on your function, though it is not tight.

Usually we are interested in a *simple* function which is an asymptotic lower bound. Moreover, when possible, we want our lower bound to be *tight*.

A function $g(n)$ is a tight asymptotic lower bound for a function $f(n)$, in symbols $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$, if the following holds:

> There exist $N,C,c>0$ such that for all $n \geq N$: $Cg(n) \geq f(n) \geq cg(n)$.

(For the experts: a more permissive definition would ask that $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ but $f(n) \neq \Omega(h(n))$ whenever $h(n) = \omega(g(n))$. As an example, $1$ is a tight asymptotic lower bound on $n(\sin n + 1) + 1$.)

Every function is its own tight asymptotic lower bound. In your case, the simpler function $n^2$ is also a tight asymptotic lower bound on $f(n)$. Indeed, we can take $N = 1$, $C = 5$, $c = 3$. For all $n \geq 1$:
$$
5n^2 \geq 3n^2 + 2n \geq 3n^2.
$$
Hence $3n^2 + 2n = \Theta(n^2)$, which is probably the answer that was expected.